# Get GPU Processor Usage Programmatically

Tags: windows, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

Is there is anyway to get the **GPU processor usage** using **CUDA**. I want to get the processor usage of each GPU connected in a cluster and to assign the job to the GPU having least processor usage.

Operating system i am using is **Windows 7 64bit**. All the connected GPUs have fermi architecture

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NVIDIA Management Library is a C-based API for monitoring and managing various states of the NVIDIA GPU devices. It provides a direct access to the queries and commands exposed via the cmdline tool `nvidia-smi`.

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml

Comment: But the GPU utilization API in NVIDIA Management Library will work only in the Fermi/Kepler based Tesla and Quadro graphics cards. I want to get the utilization in the GeForce series also.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi in that case. GeForce GPUs are not really meant for cluster building so they lack cluster management functionalities.